# UIButton does not show on iPhone 5S

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton

I am making an app for iPhone it works fine on iPhone 4S, iPhone 5, 5C but on iPhone 5S it does not show the UIButton at the bottom here is the UIButton code which I am adding which is visible on all devices except iPhone 5S.

```
createProtocolButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

createProtocolButton.frame = CGRectMake(25,648,270,47);

[createProtocolButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Blue.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


[scrollView addSubview:createProtocolButton];
[createProtocolButton addTarget:self action:@selector(createProtocolButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


createLabel = [[UILabel alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,5,270,42)];

createLabel.text=@"CREATE PROTOCOL";
createLabel.font =[UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro-Bold" size:17];

createLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

createLabel.textAlignment= NSTextAlignmentCenter;

[createProtocolButton addSubview:createLabel];
```

I found that as iPhone 5S is 64 bit may be there is some in code to add to work fine for iPhone 5S.

Here is the screen shots link for iPhone 5S where button is not showing after list

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kds899sz1oy57bg/iPhone%205S.PNG

and here is the link for iPhone 5

https://www.dropbox.com/s/z8ow0fgmisdxhm6/iPhone5.png

Comment: Try a position of something smaller in both the x and y range, this way youll know whether the button is definitely on the screen since the x and y values would be small, if it is, then its just a case of positioning the button correctly for an iPhone 5s.

Comment: check y value of button frame. It should not be 648 because height of 5s is 568

Comment: @Indrajeet I am addding button on ScrollView so height should be matter

Comment: add some screenshots

Comment: @iDeve i have shared link for screens please check thansk

Comment: add the button at the top and see whether it really appears. If it does, the issue might be with your autolayout. just a wild guess

Answer (score 0):

You can try 2-3 things for making it work :-

1) Try to add Button on top by using **"bringSubviewToFront"** method.

2) Remove table view and see whether button appearing or not within 568 height first, i know u are adding on scrollview but try it.

3) Change the y coord for button with tableview on the screen.

4) You can run a for loop on a scrollview and get all subviews inside it and then check the frame of button.

Just try these options and hopefully you will either solve your problem or at least get the problem.

Answer (score 0):

createProtocolButton.frame = CGRectMake(25,648,270,47);

Just change the 'Y' position within the screen height which is(0-568) in iphone5s.